# Java Heap Space and GC limit Error on failsafe plugin

Tags: cucumber, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm running cucumber tests using integration tests by failsafe plugin. There are around 16000 tests running altogether.I'm getting below error and stacktrace.

```
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:265)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:239)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:231)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.report.DefaultReporterFactory.mergeTestHistoryResult(DefaultReporterFactory.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.report.DefaultReporterFactory.close(DefaultReporterFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:990)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:824)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:722)*

On increasing xmx and maxpermsize the error gets changed as : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

My pom is :
                    *<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/features/**/*Tests.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <argLine>-javaagent:myOwnAgent.jar</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>*

Why is it generating sure fire stacktrace, is also one of the question.
```

Comment: Which plugins are you using?

Comment: I'm executing mvn clean verify using failsafe plugin

Comment: Are you running Cucumber-JUnit with step notifications enabled? It was the the default in earlier versions of Cucumber.

Comment: Yes it is enabled. Would it effect report generation as the stacktrace displays ?

Comment: Each step is reported as an individual test case. I expect that will take up more memory. You may also wan to disable output capture and anything else that eats up memory. Or add more headspace.

Comment: I was trying @CucumberOptions(junit = "--no-step-notifications") as mentioned on https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1360 but this is giving me compile time error.  cucumber-java version is 1.2.4

Comment: That version is rather old. Latest is v5. Note that the groupId has changed.